# Visual studio 2008 IDE gets slow

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance

Well, this happens only for the first time. But it does really screw me out.
I open my solution file in VS 2008 (which has 18 projects), open up a class file, and start typing the code in it. The moment I type in the very first character in that code file, VS 2008 hangs and waits for more than a minute to write that character. From then onwards it goes smoothly.
Why is this delay happening? Any resolutions??

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio in safe mode which disables all plug-ins? Some plug-ins (like CodeRush and Resharper) need to parse the project files before they offer their assistance and this can be slow. Visual Studio too needs to internally assemble the Intellisense lists which also slow down initial startup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any messages in the footer of Visual Studio which would indicate it is parsing the solution? You could try deleting the intellisense database, it will be a .ncb file (you will need to do this with your solution closed) and then reopen the solution, it will rebuild the intellisense database and should be faster.

You can also turn it off, I'm guessing that as you write code it is trying to do a variable/function/class/namespace lookup. To disable it follow these instructions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense-vstipedit0054.aspx

or you can do it through a macro if you want to just enable/disable it

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/11/19/controlling-intellisense-through-macros.aspx

The other thing is you may have some insidious behaviour going on that has nothing to do with the above and the only way to know is to use something like Process Monitor:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

This will tell you what files, registry keys, threads etc.. are being created, opened, closed etc. by visual studio.

Hope this helps.